# Use ToList() in Linq and Exe Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Below is an example from my textbook:

```
var allGenres = from genre in myEntities.Genres.Include("Reviews")
                orderby genre.Name
                select new { genre.Name, genre.Reviews };
Repeater1.DataSource = allGenres.ToList();
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

and the book says:

*as soon as you call ToList(), the query is executed and the relevant genres and reviews are retrieved from the database and assigned to the DataSource property*

so my question is, if I get rid of `Repeater1.DataSource = allGenres.ToList();`, what does var allGenres contain? since the query hasn't been executed?

Comment: Think of `allGenres` as a shopping list, and `ToList` as actually going to the supermarket and doing the shopping. `allGenres` knows what needs to be done. `ToList` **gets it done**. _Specifically, it contains an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type._

Comment: `allGenres` will contain the expression. If you don't call `ToList` on it or iterate over it, it will never even hit your database to retrieve the results. My guess is even if you didn't call `ToList` before doing `DataBind`, it will most likely still work because the `Repeater` will most likely iterate over the `DataSource` although this could cause performance issues later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object `allGenres` is an object that implements `IQueryable<...>`. This means that it represents a sequence, and it has functions to get the first element of the sequence, and once you've got the element you can get the next one, until there are no more elements.

The `<...>` part defines what kind of elements are in the sequence. So `IQueryable<Book>` says that you can query for a sequence of `Books`, which you can enumerate one after another. Every element of the sequence will be an object of class `Book`

This enumeration is provided using a base interface of IQueryable, namely `IEnumerable<Book>`.

At the lowest level, this Enumeration is done as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = ... // for example new List<Book>(), or new Book[10]
IEnumerator<Book> bookEnumerator = books.Getenumerator();

// as long as there are books, print the title:
// the first MoveNext() moves to the first element
// every other MoveNext() move to the next element
// it returns false if there is no such element (no first, or no next)
while (bookEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // the enumerator points to the next element. Property Current contains this element
    Book book = bookEnumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(book.Title);
}
```

Normally we won't use this low level functionality. You'll see the foreach var more often:

```
foreach (Book book in books)
{
    Console.WriteLine(book.Title);
}
```

`foreach` will do the `GetEnumerator()` / `MoveNext()` / `Current` for you

Note that the `IEnumerable` does not represent the enumeration itself, it represents **the ability to enumerate**. Quite often people are not that precise, and call the IEnumerable the sequence itself. But remember: to access the elements of the sequence you need to Enumerate over them (either by using MoveNext, or by calling foreach).

An `IQueryable<...>` seems very similar as an `IEnumerable<...>`. The difference is that it is usually meant to be processed by a different process, like a database management system, or a server on a different computer, it can also represent the lines in a CSV file, or whatever. The purpose of the IQueryable is to separate how the data is fetched from the manipulation of the fetched data.

Just like an IEnumerable holds the **ability to enumerate**, the **IQueryable hold the ability to query data**.

For this, the `IQueryable` has an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` defines in a generic way **what** data must be fetched. The `Provider` knows **who** must provide the data (the database), and what language this data provider needs (SQL).

Perhaps you have noticed there are two kinds of LINQ statements. The ones that return an IQueryable and the ones that don't. The first group are functions like `Where`, `Select`,  `Join`, `GroupBy`. They all return an IQueryable of some kind.

As long as you concatenate functions of this group, the Expression is changed. The query is not executed yet. The return value is still an object that represents the **ability to query**. These functions use *deferred execution* (or lazy execution), meaning that the query is not executed yet. You'll recognize these functions because they return `IQueryable<...>`. The remarks section of the description of these function also mentions that execution is deferred.

Only after you call `GetEnumerator()` / `MoveNext()`, either directly, or indirectly using `foreach` the query is executed.

If you start enumerating, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`, who will translate the `Expression` into the language that the executor of the query understands (SQL) and will order the executor to execute the query. The fetched data is converted to an `IEnumerable<...>` which is then enumerated as if the data was local.

It depends a bit on who made the Provider, but sometimes the Provider is really smart. it doesn't fetch all millions of Products from your products database, but it fetches a Page of Products. While you enumerate over this page the Provider fetches the next page. This will improve processing speed because there won't be fetched much more products than you actually will use, besides you can start enumerating before all Products are fetched.

I mentioned the LINQ functions that use deferred execution (= return IQueryable). The other group of functions will execute the query. This group of functions contain functions like `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, `Max`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Count` They don't return `IQueryable<...>`, but some `TResult`. If you look at the source code (google for "reference source queryable tolist"), you will see that they will do this by calling foreach or GetEnumerator.

Because the `Expression` must be translated to SQL, the query has less possibilities than an `IEnumerable<...>`. For instance, you can't use any locally defined methods in your query. If you do that, you will get a run-time exception as soon as the query is executed, telling you that the expression can't be translated into SQL.

What kind of expressions can be executed depends on who must execute your query. There is a [list of Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods for ling-to-entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities).

Answer (score 2):

There are three stages to understand.

1. First, when the query is created.
2. Second, when the query variable is iterated over (deferred execution).
3. Third, forcing a query for immediate results.

   `var allGenres = from genre in myEntities.Genres.Include("Reviews")
               orderby genre.Name
               select new { genre.Name, genre.Reviews };`

In this code, the query is only created. Its dead as a person in a cemetery. 
If you need deferred execution, then you can iterate over the results using for loop etc.

To force immediate execution, you can use conversion operators like

```
ToList, ToArray, ToLookup, and ToDictionary.
```

Hope it helps.

You can put a breakpoint on this line:

```
var allGenres = from genre in myEntities.Genres.Include("Reviews")
            orderby genre.Name
            select new { genre.Name, genre.Reviews };
```

and notice nothing happens. After the following line, *voila* SQL Profiler will display the sql query happening:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = allGenres.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework the allGeneres will be an instance of `IQueryable<Genre>` interface. The behavior is called deferred execution. For More reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution